# NoSuchElement exception with Selenium even after using Wait and checking page_soure

Tags: python, selenium, exception, phantomjs

I have this simple scraper that I am running. I am trying to scrape the search results for letter q from sam.gov:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
letter = 'q'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

driver.get("http://sam.gov")

#element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
#                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1"))
#            )
#element.click()
driver.find_element_by_id('pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1').click()

driver.find_element_by_id(letter).send_keys(letter)
driver.find_element_by_id('RegSearchButton').click()


def crawl():
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
    tableList = bsObj.find_all("table", {"class":"width100 menu_header_top_emr"}) 
    tdList = bsObj.find_all("td", {"class":"menu_header width100"})

    for table in tableList:
        item = table.find_all("span", {"class":"results_body_text"})
        print item[0].get_text().strip() + ', ' + item[1].get_text().strip() 

if driver.find_element_by_id('anch_16'):
    crawl()
    driver.find_element_by_id('anch_16').click()
    print "Going to next page"
else:
    crawl()
    print "Done with last page" 

driver.quit()
```

When i run it gives a weird error which is bothering me:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "save.py", line 22, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id('pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1').click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 269, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1'","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"153","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:40423","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"id\", \"sessionId\": \"eb7dfa50-70a7-11e6-b125-9ff4e2dbd485\", \"value\": \"pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/eb7dfa50-70a7-11e6-b125-9ff4e2dbd485/element"}}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

I have since tried using an implicit wait of 60 right after i initialize the browser. No luck

I have also tried webdriverwait (commented out in the code right below `driver.get("http://sam.gov")`, and it gave me at TimeOutException.

The weird thing is if i do a `print driver.page_source` right after the get call, the source is fine and it contains the following code which actually contains the element with the id that I am searching for. There is no frame or iframe either.

```
<a id="pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1" href="#" title="Search Records" onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12'),{'pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1':'pbG220e071f_2de75f_2d417d_2d9c61_2d027d324c8fec:_viewRoot:j_id12:search1'},'');}return false" class="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Id locator of the element looks like dynamically generated, you should try some different locator.

You can try using `css_selector` as below:-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.button[title='Search Records']").click()
```

Or using `WebDriverWait` as:-

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.button[title='Search Records']")))
element.click()
```

**Note** :- Before finding element make sure it's not inside any `frame/iframe`. If it's inside any `frame/iframe` you need to switch that `frame/iframe` before finding element as `driver.switch_to_frame("frame/iframe id or name")`